# When i use IronBarCode library it gives error

Tags: c#, ironbarcode

Whe i use

`BrcodeWriter.CreateBarcode("firstWord", BarcodeWriterEncoding.QRCode).SaveAsJpeg("QuickStart.jpg");'`

Visual Studio give me error:

```Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`, referenced by `IronBarCode`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`, or remove the reference to `IronBarCode`. Maket.Android

Comment: Have you tried adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` NuGet package to your project? If it's not a NuGet package, this may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: Yes, its not working